# Qual a diferença entre arquivos encodados com BOM e sem BOM?

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres

A um bom tempo eu enfrentei problemas com formatação de arquivos entre *ISO-**, *UTF-8*, *ANSII* e outros, passei a pesquisar formas de solucionar estes problemas, encontrei várias formas diferentes, tanto usando ferramentas, quanto usando linguagens de programação, porém uma coisa que eu nunca me aprofundei a saber é:
Qual a diferença estrural entre um arquivo sem *BOM* e um com *BOM*?