# Problema de acentuação de saída de arquivo salvo no equipamento

Tags: python-2.7, acentuação

Bom galera eu tenho o seguinte arquivo salvo em meu equipamento "nomes.txt", sendo esse contendo 1190 linhas. Segue meu código python2.7:

```
#/usr/bin/python env
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

abrir = open("nomes.txt", "r")

for a in abrir:
    print a.strip()

abrir.close()
```

Porém quando ele me mostra a saída, alguns nomes com acentos ele vem no seguinte formato:

```
T�ri
Thais
Thauany
Thayn�
Thelma
Tiana
Ticiana
Tricia
T�nia
```

Já tentei colocando o u antes e continua assim, inclusive tentei usando pprint na qual a saída foi de forma bruta mostrando. Mostrando outros caracteres no acento, devido ao python reconhecer apenas ASCII. Alguém teria idéia do que pode estar acontecendo.

Comment: Executei seu código aqui e reconheceu os acentos.

Comment: Estranho, pode ser então a saída do ipython2. Vou testar aqui pela terminal do linux.

Comment: Eu rodei pelo terminal.

Comment: rodei aqui agora, ainda continua com a saída ruim. Z�lio
Zen�bio
Zeus

Comment: Sinceramente não faço idéia do que possa ser, acabei de abrir o IDLE do python2.7 aqui, escrevi o código na unha e a saída ainda retorna ruim

Comment: Salve o arquivo `nomes.txt` como UTF8 sem BOM e tente novamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso mesmo resolveu

Comment: Eu uso linux eu fiz o seguinte abri o nomes.txt com o gedit dei um salvar como, ai no próprio gedit ele tem as opções de qual formatação utilizar ai coloquei utf-8 e rodei o código pronto resolveu

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca havia me esquecido do Gnome, faz tempo que não uso liunx :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade nem uso Gnome, eu uso arch linux com xfce :)

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca a sim é que a maioria dos ambientes graficos tem algumas ferramentas do Gnome hehehehe, também gosto do Xfce :)

Comment: A isso e verdade, algumas sempre usa umas ferramentas do gnome mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salve o document .txt como **utf8 sem BOM** e vai resolver.

- Usando notepad++:

  [image: utf8 sem bom notepad++]
- Usando Sublime Text:

  [image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]
- Vim:

  Defina o `fileencoding` como `utf8` (acredito que já fique sem BOM)

  ```
  :set fileencoding=utf8
  :w arquivo.txt
  ```

Comment: o que seria este BOM do utf-8

Comment: Achei a resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-arquivos-encodados-com-bom-e-sem-bom

Comment: @GlaucioFonseca vou linkar depois, obrigado