# Encoding sem configuração: Eclipse (JSP) e VSCode

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, codificação-de-caracteres, visual-studio-code

Estou com alguns problemas relacionados a encoding. Tanto no eclipse quanto no Visual Studio Code estão apontados para o UTF-8.
Quando eu conserto e salvo usando o eclipse, ele vai de boa. Mas quando eu salvo no VSCode, o encoding desconfigura.

Segue um exemplo:
[image: Encoding desconfigurado ao salvar no eclipse]

Eu uso o eclipse só para compilar a minha aplicação, e me sinto muito mais confortável ao desenvolver no VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver [em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38528627/2387977) seu VSCode, confirme se a configuração está correta:

1. Vá em **File** -> **Preferences** -> **User Settings**
2. Adicione a entrada
   `"files.encoding": "utf8"` na janela da direita e salve.

Você também pode optar por adicionar apenas a entrada:

```
"files.autoGuessEncoding": true
```

E deixar com que o Visual Studio Code adivinhe o encoding do arquivo aberto, como explicado [na documentação](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> When enabled, will attempt to guess the character set encoding when opening files. This setting can be configured per language too.

Comment: No meu VSCode já se encontra nessa configuração: "files.encoding": "utf8"

Comment: @ThiagoCunha tentou usar o `files.autoGuessEncoding`? O problema pode estar também no Eclipse (usando outro encoding diferente de UTF-8)

Comment: Tentei sim! Fui lá no eclipse, e ainda esta sendo usado o UTF-8, inclusive na configuração do projeto.

Comment: @ThiagoCunha, está usando Windows? Se sim, abra o arquivo no Notepad, vá em Arquivo > Salvar Como e veja o que aparece selecionado no campo "Codificação"

Comment: ANSI, UTF-8, UNICODE, UNICODE BIG Endian

Comment: Qual aparece selecionada quando você abre o arquivo? Este é o encoding atual do arquivo. Pedi isto para você para confirmar o encoding do arquivo.

Comment: No meu eclipse esta:Text file encoding: UTF-8/ New text file line demimiter: Unix

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79484/discussion-between-dherik-and-thiago-cunha).

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui isolar o problema e acabei descobrindo que esse problema é herdado do eclipse. Para tal teste, fiz os seguintes procedimentos:

1. Criei arquivos no VSCode e no Bloco de Notas com extensão .txt, e ambos abriram normalmente
2. Criei arquivos em ambas as aplicações com a extensão .jsp. Quando eu criei e passei do eclipse para outras aplicações, gerou problema de caracter. Quando criei também no bloco de notas e no VSCode, os dois se comunicaram bem, mas quando abri no Eclipse, deu erro nos caracteres.

Então, erro no eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde pessoal,

Primeiramente desculpa pela pobreza de argumentações.

Fiz um teste no VS alterando o encoding (File > Preferences > Settings > Files: Encoding) para **utf8bom** (Byte order mark). Parece que ele não traz grandes implicações para o projeto. (Fonte: [Qual a diferença entre arquivos encodados com BOM e sem BOM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-arquivos-encodados-com-bom-e-sem-bom) )

Deste modo, o Eclipse passou a identificar as acentuações corretamente.

Espero ter ajudado!