# Listar Arquivos por extensão - PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando listar os arquivos de uma pasta.
Depois de executar o cod. abaixo, ocorre o erro:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\01-Signer\testeAssinador.php on line 23**

Pessoalmente, eu não consigo ver onde está o erro. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigada!

```
$_path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\01-Signer\Fev19';
if(is_dir($_path)){

  foreach(glob("$_path\*.txt") as $arquivo){
   echo "Nome do Arquivo: <a href='$arquivo'>$arquivo</a><br />";
  }
 }else{
  
  echo 'Não existe arquivo com extensão pdf.';
 }
```

Comment: O resutlado de `glob("$_path\*.txt")` tem que colocar dentro de uma variável, e usar essa variável no `foreach`

Comment: @EdwardRamos Por que precisa colocar em uma variável?

Comment: E o que eu vi nessa pergunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805963/using-glob-to-get-txt-and-png-files-only-from-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @EdwardRamos A pergunta é de php. Python e PHP são diferentes.

Comment: Coloquei o glob("$_path\*.txt") em uma variável, mas continua dando erro (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\01-Signer\testeAssinador.php on line 26)

Comment: @Renata https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php e https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-glob-find-files/

Comment: @Renata Seu código está correto, mas parece que há caracteres invisíveis interferindo no seu arquivo. Reveja a forma como está escrevendo o código ou cuide de onde copia e cola. Reescrevi o seu código (https://repl.it/@acwoss/AllBlushingRatio) e ele funcionou perfeitamente como o esperado.

Comment: @EdwardRamos Querer ajudar é muito bom, não entenda mal, mas ajudar dando palpites aleatórios sem fundamento tendem a atrapalhar mais do que ajudar. Se não tem certeza se resolve o problema, teste antes e veja se funciona. Se funcionar, veja se consegue justificar porque resolveu. Uma solução sem a justificativa também não ajuda muito. Recomendo o repl.it para os testes, assim como fiz acima.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ao analisar os caracteres do seu código temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Resultado gerado por https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php</sup>

Todos esses caracteres marcados em azul são caracteres "invisíveis" que parecem ser espaços em branco normais. Isso acontece porque você não está utilizando um editor de código para escrever os códigos ou copiou o código de outro lugar e acabou trazendo esses caracteres juntos.

Se remover todos os caracteres indevidos o seu código funcionará perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Após validação do [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) em um comentário na sua pergunta, o problema que está enfrentando deve ser mitigado tendo atenção aos seguintes pontos:

1. Seu editor de textos cria arquivos em qual codificação?

O recomendado (ou uma boa prática) é trabalhar com UTF-8

2. Se seu editor cria códigos em UTF-8 é com ou sem `BOM`?

o BOM é uma assinatura que define o tipo de codificação para arquivos UTF-8. A resposta dessa pergunta deve esclarecer melhor: [Qual a diferença entre arquivos encodados com BOM e sem BOM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16556/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-arquivos-encodados-com-bom-e-sem-bom)

O problema causado por estar com codificações de arquivo conflitantes é que provavelmente existem caracteres ocultos que o interpretador do PHP tentará executar.

Uma boa dica ao trabalhar com Windows é usar o Notepad++ que oferece a possibilidade de configurar a codificação do arquivo que está escrevendo, mas minha recomendação pessoal é trabalhar com PHPStorm, ele deixa tudo isso transparente ;)

E, por fim, seu código está correto, mas a reescrita do Anderson melhorou a leitura, atente-se a isso também :D