# Como salvar texto Unicode em um arquivo .JSON sem a sequência de escape?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, codificação-de-caracteres, unicode

Estou criando um programa onde eu preciso salvar dentro um de arquivo JSON um dicionário que contém strings com caracteres Unicode. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import json

data = {"face": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"}

with open("file.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
```

O problema é que sempre que eu salvo o arquivo, todos os caracteres Unicode são convertidos para seus respectivos códigos `\uXXX` e eu preciso que o arquivo possua os textos originais.

No caso do exemplo acima, o conteúdo do arquivo criado pelo programa ficou assim:

```
{
    "face": "( \u0361\u00b0 \u035c\u0296 \u0361\u00b0)"
}
```

Eu preciso que os caracteres permaneçam os mesmos para que o conteúdo fique visualmente agradável ao usuário. Como eu poderia manter o texto original ?

Comment: Qual versão do python está utilizando? Está usando `#coding: utf-8` no inicio do arquivo?

Comment: Estou utilizando Python 3 e os arquivos `.py` e `.json` estão codificados em UTF-8. Mas não, eu não comentei isso no meu código.

Comment: eu testei setando o ensure_ascii = False  do json.dumps e funcionou aqui, da uma olhadinha nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence

Comment: Cara, eu não sei se tu percebeu, mas o arquivo que vc está lendo não é o mesmo que está gravando. Testei o seu código e deu certo local. Porém tive que mudar o nome do arquivo pra o correto.

Comment: @Danizavtz Eu sei que não é o mesmo que está gravando. Aqueles dois são realmente arquivos diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado @ErickKokubum, sua dica funcionou para resolver a parte da escrita do arquivo.

Comment: O `UnicodeDecodeError` provavelmente é porque o other_file.txt não foi salvo em UTF-8 (eu só consegui simular o erro gerando um arquivo em UTF-16 e tentando ler como UTF-8).

Comment: @hkotsubo Não é possível porque eu estou salvando o arquivo em UTF-8. Estou utilizando o bloco de notas do Windows, tem problema nisso ?

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu consegui ler o arquivo salvando ele com o encoding `utf-8-sig`. Eu não faço ideia da diferença entre ele para o UTF-8, mas essa foi a única codificação que conseguiu ler o arquivo.

Comment: Então o arquivo está em UTF-8 mas foi salvo com o [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16556/112052), esse encoding utf8-sig serve para ignorar o BOM: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data

Comment: @hkotsubo Se eu salvar meu arquivo em um outro editor que não grava com esse BOM, vai dar erro na leitura por usar o `utf-8-sig` ou eu posso utilizar essa codificação sem ou com BOM ?

Comment: Não lembro (mas acho que sim), só testando pra saber :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Ok obrigado. Eu editei a pergunta para que fique apenas com o assunto da criação do arquivo. Acho essa uma boa pergunta. Seria possível avalia-la ?

Comment: Sim, agora melhorou. Antes tinha 2 problemas não necessariamente relacionados na mesma pergunta

Comment: Só pra complementar, segue [trecho da documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode): "*Microsoft invented a variant of UTF-8 (that Python 2.5 calls "utf-8-sig") for its Notepad program: Before any of the Unicode characters is written to the file, a UTF-8 encoded BOM (which looks like this as a byte sequence: 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) is written. ...On decoding utf-8-sig will skip those three bytes if they appear as the first three bytes in the file. In UTF-8, the use of the BOM is discouraged and should generally be avoided.*"

Comment: E pra terminar, se estiver lendo/escrevendo arquivos, não precisa chamar `read` e `write`, basta fazer `data = json.load(file)` e `json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)` (os métodos são `load` e `dump`, sem o "s" no final - as versões com "s" - `loads` e `dumps` - são usadas para trabalhar diretamente com strings - se bem que não deve fazer diferença no resultado final...)

Answer (score 1):

Assim como o [Erick](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/142747/erick-kokubum) falou nos comentários, essa conversão acontece no método `json.dumps` por causa do parâmetro `ensure_ascii` que é definido por padrão para `True`. O que esse parâmetro faz é assegurar que a saída conterá somente caracteres ASCII.

Sendo assim, defina o valor do parâmetro para `False` como no código abaixo para que ele mantenha os caracteres Unicode sem convertê-los:

```
import json

data = {"face": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"}
content = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False)

print(content) # '{"face": "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)"}'
```